# jqGrid sort by Date and Time format

Tags: jquery, sorting, datetime, jqgrid

How can i sort my table by date and time? This is my sample code

colModel

```
 var sh2cols = [

     {name: 'date_time', width:85, sorttype: 'date', align: "right",
     formatter: 'date', formatoptions: {srcformat: 'ISO8601Long',
     srcformat:'M d, Y h:i:s', newformat: 'M d, Y h:i:s'}},

     {name:'Person', width: 85, align: 'center', 
      sortable: true, fixed: true, hidden: false}
     ...
]
```

My input is like this **"Jul 31, 2015 16:58:05"**  but the display in table is like this **"NaN 16:58:05"** and if i click the column to sort it become like this **"undefined NaN, NaN 12:NaN:NaN"**. Any idea guys what is wrong? I'm using **jqGrid** plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this,
index is the key for sorting.

```
{ name: 'date_time', index: 'date_time', width:85, sorttype: "datetime", formatter: "date", formatoptions: { srcformat: "m/d/Y h:i:s A", newformat: "m/d/Y h:i:s A" }}
```